# Navigation bar View Controller is twice the size as others

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, navigationcontroller

I have a multiple View Controllers embedded in Navigation Controller and one of my navigation bars is twice the size(extends down twice as much) as every other one. I want all of these bars to be the same size,  but can't find anyway to change the size in Inspector. There are no bar buttons on this Navigation Bar. Any ideas for a quick fix w/o having to rebuild this VC?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a custom background image for the nav bar in question?

Comment: Yes. I put in an image the is a narrow bar shape. I took image out,  but the bar item is still extends down

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Default `UINavigationBar` have a height of 44 points and it can't be changed. I think you have a constraint issue: select your wrong sized `UINavigationBar` and on the top right corner, in the "utilities", select "size inspector". Then, have a look at the severals constraints, edit and/or delete some.

Comment: The "size inspector" for the Navigation Bar Item only has N/A.  not able to control constraints.